How to split a variable into 2 variables in pseudo c code generated by IDA?
Some times IDA's decompiler translates more than variables into a single variable or an array of varibles, for example, I have 2 variables
A a; // size = 30h
B b; // size = 60h

but IDA gives
A arr[3];

how can I split them out?

You can redefine the type of the variable by right clicking on its name anywhere in the function and selecting "Set lvar type", or by pressing the Y key. Afterwards, IDA will automatically create new variables that will fill in the remaining stack space, you can also redefine their type if needed.
